Разный лендинг для разных пользователей
Как мне сделать так, чтобы при запросе разных пользователей, допустим, по кнопке в телеграм-боте, создавалась ссылка на заготовленный лендинг с инпутами и если юзер туда что-то вводит, то мне бы в телеграм приходили эти данные с пометкой, кто создал эту ссылку. Я нормально не могу сформулировать, поэтому очень прошу, подсобите ссылкой на темы по этому поводу.
